# What's the name of this theorem: $\int_a^b|u_n-u|^pdt\rightarrow0\wedge\int_a^b|u_n'-v|^pdt\rightarrow0\Rightarrow u\in W_p^1(a,b) \ : \ u'=v$?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, analysis, sobolev-spaces, sequence-of-function

My Professor gave me this as an exercise to prove, that:

$$\int_a^b|u_n(t) -u(t)|^pdt\rightarrow0\wedge\int_a^b|u_n(t)'-v(t)|^pdt\rightarrow0\Rightarrow u(t)\in W_p^1(a,b) \ : \ u'(t)=v(t)$$

given, that we're in $L_p \left[a,b\right]$ space for $1 \le p < \infty$, and our sequence $(u_n)$ is taken so, that $\forall n \ u_n \in W_p^1 (a,b)$ (Sobolev Space).

He didn't give me the name for that theorem though, he just said that it's "one of the most fundamental ones in functional analysis" and that "its proof is not that trivial".

Comment: Looks like one step in the proof that $W^{1,p}$ is complete.

Comment: That's what I also thought. But assuming we already know that $W^{1,p}$ is complete: What's the next step? What I thought is, that the Sobolev norm of $u_n - u$ must converge to zero, because there would exist a limit $u \in W^{1,p}$ such, that a sequence $(u_n) \in W^{1,p}$ would converge to $u$ in the Sobolev norm. We would then have: $\lVert u_n - u \rVert_{p,1} = \lVert u_n - u \rVert_p + \lVert u_n' - u' \rVert_p \rightarrow 0$ We already know by assumption, that $\lVert u_n - u \rVert_p \rightarrow 0$. So it must also be true that $ \lVert u_n' - u' \rVert_p \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: We know from assumption, that $ \lVert u_n' - v \rVert_p \rightarrow 0$. And what I thought was to argue that "due to the uniqueness of the limit in the $L_p$ norm", it must be also true that $u' = v$. Thus, we've shown that $u \in W^{1,p}$ and $u' = v$. Am I missing something, or is that the proof?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this statement has its own name. However, one can rephrase it in a more descriptive language:

> **Thm. 1.** The subspace $\{ (u,u') : u \in W^{1,p} \}$ is a closed subspace of $L^p \oplus L^p$.

As mentioned by daw, this is related to:

> **Thm. 2.** The space $W^{1,p}$ is complete.

I see four things that could be said about these two statements, and none of them is really hard.

---

**Proof of Thm. 1**

Given $u_n$, $u$ and $v$ as in your question, it's enough to justify that $u'=v$. To this end, fix a test function $\varphi \in C_c^\infty((a,b))$. Given that
$$ 0 = \int_a^b u_n' \varphi + u_n \varphi' $$
for each $n$, we can pass to the limit and obtain
$$ 0 = \int_a^b v \varphi + u \varphi'. $$
This is nothing else than saying $u' = v$ in the weak sense.

---

**Proof of Thm. 2 given Thm. 1**

Since $V = \{ (u,u') : u \in W^{1,p} \}$ is a closed subspace of the complete space $L^p \oplus L^p$, then $V$ has to be complete as well. Note that $V$ is isometric to $W^{1,p}$ by the map
$$ W^{1,p} \ni u \mapsto (u, u') \in V, $$
so $W^{1,p}$ is complete too.

---

**Proof of Thm. 1 given Thm. 2**

This is a very strange thing to do, but since OP asked for it in a comment, here it goes.

If $W^{1,p}$ is known to be complete, then $V$ is also complete as its isometric copy. Then $V \subseteq L^p \otimes L^p$ has to be a closed subspace. This last implication doesn't even use completeness of $L^p$.

---

**Reflexivity of $W^{1,p}$**

OK, nobody asked about it, but it's important. It is a consequence of Hahn-Banach that any closed subspace of a reflexive space is also reflexive. In the case $p > 1$ the space $L^p \oplus L^p$ is reflexive, and thus so is $V$, and finally also $W^{1,p}$.

Comment: I don't understand how your proof of Theorem 1 should prove this theorem. I simply don't see the connection between $V$ being a closed subspace of $L_p \oplus L_p$ and your proof

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? Being closed means that whenever you have a sequence $(u_n,v_n)$ in the subspace (which means that $u_n'=v_n$) and $(u_n,v_n) \to (u,v)$, then the limit also lies in the subspace (which means that $u'=v$).
Edit: There was a typo in that proof, maybe that was the problem.

Comment: We never had this "test function" and "in the weak sense", that's what I don't understand

Comment: The phrases _test function_ and _weak sense_ correspond to one of the standard ways to introduce Sobolev spaces. What is the definition of $W^{1,p}$ you're using? And what do you mean by $u'=v$? I'd recommend including this info in your question.