# How can I show that the Sobolev space $W_p^1 (a,b)$ is closed?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, complete-spaces, absolute-continuity

We define the Sobolev space $W_p^1 (a,b)$ as:

$$W_p^1 (a,b) = \left\{ u \in L_p (a,b) \ : \ u \in AC\left[a, b\right], \ u' \in L_p \left[a, b\right] \right\}$$

where $AC\left[a,b\right]$ means "absolutely continuous on $\left[a,b\right]$. We defined absolute continuity as follows:

> $u$ is absolutely continuous on $\left[a,b\right]$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $u(x) = u(a) + \int_a^x v(t) dt$ for $x \in (a,b)$

We know, that $W_p^1 (a,b) \subset L_p (a,b)$.

We also know, that if $X$ is a complete space, then $A \subset X$ is complete $\Leftrightarrow$ if $A$ is closed

The space $L_p (a,b)$ is complete. So, in order to prove that $W_p^1 (a,b)$ is also complete, we only have to show that $W_p^1 (a,b)$ is closed.

But how exactly? By using the complement of $W_p^1 (a,b)$? By creating a sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space $W^{1,p}$ is **not** closed as a subset of $L^p$. To see this, consider the subspace of all $C^1$ compactly supported functions:
$$
C_c^1 \subseteq W^{1,p} \subseteq L^p.
$$
You're probably familiar with the fact that $C_c^1$ is dense in $L^p$. This means that $\overline{C_c^1} = L^p$, so in particular also $\overline{W^{1,p}} = L^p$ (a larger subset has a larger closure).

---

This argument proves that $W^{1,p}$ with the $L^p$ norm is **not** a complete space. However, $W^{1,p}$ **is** complete with its own norm
$$
\| u \|_{W^{1,p}} := \| u \|_{L^p}+\| u' \|_{L^p}
$$
To prove completeness of $W^{1,p}$, you can indeed use completeness of $L^p$, but in another way - see [my answer to your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4417401/350803).